# Metasploitable network configuration

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux, metasploit

I am using VirtualBox v5.2.4. When I set metasploitable to NAT/NAT Network/Host-only adapter I cannot reach it when I `ping` from Kali. However, when I set it to bridged, I am able to reach it. I do understand using bridged is a security risk.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

By the way, I already went to `File >>Preferences >> Network >> Add a NAT Network` and changed the IP to `192.168.xx.xx`.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what your host is, what your guests are and what your network configuration should actually look like. It might be a good idea to read [the VirtualBox manual on networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, just in case some newbie like myself encounters same problem... my host only configuration wasn't right. I was unable to configure the DHCP server and adapter following the instructions I found elsewhere on this internet because in Virtualbox 5.2.4 for windows, the host only settings are under "Global Tools" and not File>>Preferences. After the configuration, I set both Kali and Metasploitable to Host Only adapter and everything works as expected now.